# Moving files to specific keys within buckets with Python & boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

Having trouble copying files from one point to another using boto. While I can copy them fairly easily into the top "level" of the bucket that's fine...but my buckets are made up of numerous monthly keys and when I attempt to copy a file into one of the specific keys my code gets hung up. So for example THIS WORKS but puts the file into the "main bucket" section- which is not what I'm looking to do (bucket becomes s3://mybucket/myFile.tar.gz whereas I really need the file to go into a monthly file folder- something like s3://mybucket/201507/myFile.tar.gz):

```
from ETLProcedural import ETLProceduralcls
a = ETLProceduralcls()
srcbucket = a._s3.get_bucket("mySOURCEbucket")
destbucket = a._s3.get_bucket("myDESTbucket")
source = srcbucket.get_key(“201507/myFILE.tar.gz") 
destination = destbucket.get_key(“DestSubFolder/201507/")
destbucket.copy_key(“myFILE.tar.gz", srcbucket.name,  source.key)
```

But if I try to move the file into a specific monthly file within the destination bucket I get hung up (no error- just an endless wait), so THIS DOESN'T WORK:

```
destbucket.copy_key(“DestSubFolder/201507/myFILE.tar.gz", srcbucket.name, source.key)
```

So basically wondering if anyone has experience moving files into sub-folders (sub-keys?) in s3 using boto? (as you can see-need to move into appropriate monthly folders) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `copy_key(string, string, key)` instead of `copy_key(string, string, string)`. The third parameter is a string of the key (filename), rather than the actual Key object. You can just specify the key as a string, or you could use `source.key.name`.

This worked for me:

```
>>> import boto
>>> conn=boto.connect_s3()
>>> destbucket=conn.get_bucket('bucket2')
>>> destbucket.copy_key('bar/file', 'bucket1', 'foo/file')
<Key: bucket2,bar/file>
```

It copied `s3://bucket1/foo/file` to `s3://bucket2/bar/file`.

Comment: how can i do with ios sdk?

Comment: Khunshan -- Please create a new question if you'd like to ask something different to the question.

Comment: hey john ,may i know how would i copy a file to a folder , like if no folder it should create and copy file there .... for e.g. `s3://bucket1/foo/file` to `s3://bucket2/bar/file` if no `bar` then it should create `bar` and then copy ..... I am using s3 client `copy_object` but it shows no key error

Comment: @Codenewbie Amazon S3 does not require folders. You can simply copy a file to any destination path and it will work. The folder will 'appear' to be there, but it doesn't actually exist. (BTW, the above code is now outdated. You should be using boto3.)

Comment: can you please guide me or could i open a new question of what i have tried and the issue i am facing ..

Comment: @Codenewbie Yes. Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 1):

John here provide for `boto`.

For `boto3` you can do this following

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dest = s3.Bucket('destinationbucket')
source= { 'Bucket' : 'sourcebucketname', 'Key': 'filename'}
dest.copy(source, 'destinationfilename')
```

It will copy from `sourcebucketname/filename` to `destinationbucket/destinationfilename`